# Is there anyway to make activescaffold work with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

I have a child model which `accepts_nested_attributes_for` another model in a `has_one` / `belongs_to` relationship. I am trying to configure the `activescaffold` controller like this:

```
config.create.columns = [:name, :birthdate, :device_attributes]
```

But it just throws this error:

```
undefined method `device_attributes' for #<Child:0xc103e28>
```

Note: I have overridden the default `create_form` with a custom implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it works. I just added this to the activescaffold controller:

```
  def before_create_save(record)
    record.device_attributes = params[:record][:device_attributes]
  end

  def before_update_save(record)
    record.device_attributes = params[:record][:device_attributes]
  end
```

It's not the cleaner way to do it, but i didn't find other way.